# platform.objc.objc_msgSend not work in kotlin

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

This method creates an instance of BaseId and exported to an objective-c framework to called by ios project, here is the code:

```
actual fun create(typeName: String, id: String): BaseId {
    val objCClass = NSClassFromString(typeName)
    var selector = NSSelectorFromString("alloc")
    val instance = objc_msgSend(objCClass, selector)
    selector = NSSelectorFromString("initWithId:")
    // ???????? this msgSend not work !
    objc_msgSend(instance, selector, id)
    // -------------------------------- 
    return instance as BaseId
}
```

but when I called this method in ios project like this:

```
// UserId extends BaseId
let typeName = NSStringFromClass(UserId.classForCoder())
let userId = framework.create(typeName: typeName, id: "testId")  as! UserId
// ????????  the userId is created sucessful but userId.id is empty, not the expetcting value "testId"
let userId2 = UserId.init(id: "testId2")
// userId2 is good, userId2.id == "testId2"
```

UserId.h

```
__attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted))
__attribute__((swift_name("UserId")))
@interface CommonUserId : CommonBaseId
- (instancetype)initWithId:(NSString *)id __attribute__((swift_name("init(id:)"))) __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer));
- (NSString *)testFun __attribute__((swift_name("testFun()")));
@property NSString *testProperty __attribute__((swift_name("testProperty")));
@end;
```

Is there anyone who can help me to find out what the wrong it is?

Answer (score 0):

`objc_msgSend` must be cast to appropriate functional type, per Apple recommendations, see https://mikeash.com/pyblog/objc_msgsends-new-prototype.html for technical details behind this decision.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there is another question after reading your link, how could I cast the Kotlin Function to the "True ProtoType"? I think it's impossible.